# Add custom attributes on terms.ftl page for Keycloak

Tags: attributes, keycloak, custom-attributes

I need to add some new custom attributes (booleans) on terms.ftl page, in order to inform the user about our cookies policies.

I've added some inputs of type checkbox inside the terms.ftl custom theme which are sent on the Payload, but for some reason the attributes are not saved in KC. I can only see the **Terms and conditions accepted timestamp**, which is the normal behavior of KC, saving the timestamp when the user accepted the terms.

I've also tried to manually create the attributes from KC (Realm settings > User profile > **Create attribute**).

The **Payload** for the **POST** call on **/login-actions/required-action** contain the custom attributes, but the values are not getting updated in KC after accepting the terms.

I've also tried to match the name of the input to the attribute's key, but nothing works. Can anyone help me with this, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show you added a custom attributes by image? And how to try your POST call, can you share more detail how to call it?